# Algorithm to determine whether a permutation can be generated by 2 parallel stacks

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation

The setting is similar to the stack-sortable permutation problem discussed by Knuth before, but on permutation generation with stack.
I would like to write a program to determine whether a permutation is stack-generatable with 2 stacks instead of only 1.

This is actually a homework problem, which the requirement are as follows:

> A permutation of 1 to n is a stack-generated permutation if and only
>   if it can be generated by pushing 1 to n onto a stack and popping them
>   o. For example, stack-generated permutation (2, 1, 3) can be
>   generated by doing operations push 1, push 2, pop, pop, push 3, pop.
>
> In this problem, instead of using only one stack, we use two stacks:
>   every time you can push an element to either stack, or you can pop
>   element from either stack as long as it is non-empty. However, once an
>   element is popped, it cannot be pushed back to either stack again.
>
> Your task is to determine whether a permutation can be generated by
>   using two stacks.

I know that if a permutation contain the pattern `4123`, it cannot be generated. However, doing pattern matching seems very time consuming and likely out of my ability, not to mention that I do not know whether `4123` is the only pattern.

Currently I am trying to actually generate it with 2 stacks in order to determine whether a permutation can be generated, but my algorithm can only determine some of the stack-generatable permutation. Therefore I would like to know what is the correct algorithm for this problem. An working C code would of cause be amazing, but any tips, advise or pseudo code are also good enough. Thank you!

An example permutation to determine:

```
62 61 58 53 67 66 47 65 69 68 64 45 70 71 63 44 42 60 72 59 41 73 74 57 56 39 55 54 38 37 52 51 50 49 48 76 46 43 75 40 36 35 77 34 31 30 33 29 32 78 22 79 28 27 80 20 26 25 24 23 83 82 81 85 84 87 89 21 19 90 88 92 86 95 94 18 98 96 97 93 17 15 99 91 16 100 14 12 13 9 8 11 6 5 10 7 4 3 2 1
```

My current implementation(which is very messy and has no comment, so I do not recommend you reading it):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 1000

typedef struct stack {
    int data[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
} Stack;


void push(Stack *s, int d);

int pop(Stack *s);

int peek(Stack *s);

int isEmpty(Stack *s);

int getPos(int d[], int size, int a);

void push(Stack *s, int d) {
    (*s).top++;
    (*s).data[(*s).top] = d;

}


int pop(Stack *s) {
    int d = (*s).data[(*s).top];
    (*s).top--;
    return d;
}

int peek(Stack *s) {
    if (!isEmpty(s)) {
        return (*s).data[(*s).top];
    } else return -1;
}

int isEmpty(Stack *s) {
    if ((*s).top < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else return 0;
}


int getPos(int d[], int size, int a) {
    int i = 0, al = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (d[i] == a) {
            al = i;
        }


    }
    if (al != -1) {
        return al;

    } else return -1;

}


int main() {
    int t = 0;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int failed = 0;
        int n = 0;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int target[MAXSIZE];
        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &target[j]);
        }
        Stack s1, s2;
        s1.top = -1;
        s2.top = -1;

        Stack *s1_ptr = &s1;
        Stack *s2_ptr = &s2;

        int output[MAXSIZE];
        int oh = 0;
        int th = 0;
        int k = 1;
        for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {

            int f1 = 0, f2 = 0;
            int checkAgain = 1, pushed = 0;

            while (checkAgain) {
                checkAgain = 0;

                if (k == target[th]) {
                    push(s1_ptr, k);
                    output[oh] = pop(s1_ptr);
                    oh++;
                    th++;
                    pushed = 1;

                } else if (!isEmpty(s1_ptr) && peek(s1_ptr) == target[th]) {
                    output[oh] = pop(s1_ptr);
                    oh++;
                    th++;
                    checkAgain = 1;

                } else if (!isEmpty(s2_ptr) && peek(s2_ptr) == target[th]) {
                    output[oh] = pop(s2_ptr);
                    oh++;
                    th++;
                    checkAgain = 1;

                }
            }
            if (!pushed) {
                if (isEmpty(s1_ptr)) {
                    push(s1_ptr, k);
                } else if (isEmpty(s2_ptr)) {
                    push(s2_ptr, k);
                } else {
                    int s1l = -1, s2l = -1;
                    if (peek(s1_ptr) >= 0) {
                        s1l = getPos(target, n, peek(s1_ptr));
                    }
                    if (peek(s2_ptr) >= 0) {
                        s2l = getPos(target, n, peek(s2_ptr));
                    }
                    int kl = getPos(target, n, k);
                    int canPush1 = 0, canPush2 = 0;

                    if (kl < s1l) {

                        canPush1 = 1;
                    }
                    if (kl < s2l) {

                        canPush2 = 1;
                    }
                    if (canPush1 && canPush2) {
                        if (s1l < s2l) {
                            push(s1_ptr, k);
                        } else {
                            push(s2_ptr, k);
                        }
                    } else if (canPush1 && !canPush2) {
                        push(s1_ptr, k);
                    } else if (!canPush1 && canPush2) {
                        push(s2_ptr, k);
                    } else {
                        failed = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (failed) {
            printf("No\n");
            continue;
        }

        int m = th;
        for (m = th; m < n; m++) {
            if (peek(s1_ptr) == target[th]) {
                output[oh] = pop(s1_ptr);
                oh++;
                th++;

            } else if (peek(s2_ptr) == target[th]) {
                output[oh] = pop(s2_ptr);
                oh++;
                th++;

            } else {
                failed = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (th == n) {
            printf("Yes\n");
        } else {
            printf("No\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that I may have made many grammar mistakes or simply bad language usage as I am not a native speaker. Please let me know if I did something wrong. Thank you!

Comment: To the person who down vote this question, do you mind giving me a reason for the down vote so that I can improve my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the help from two Chinese sites, as there is actually a similar question in NOIP2008, which deals with permutation sortable by 2 stacks. The solution for generatable permutation is pretty similar. I can write more later if someone is interested about the solution.

The two sites that helped me:

[NOIP2008 双栈排序 twostack 题解](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_75119ca30100xx99.html)

[NOIP2008提高组复赛题解](https://www.byvoid.com/blog/noip2008-twostack)

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN 1002
int const NEINF = -1;

int targetPermutation[MAXN];
int precalculatedMax[MAXN];
int bipartiteGraph[MAXN];
int adjacencyMatrix[MAXN][MAXN];
int N;
int noSolution = 0;

void reset();

void colouringAndCheckConflict(int i, int c);

void checkAdjacencyAndDye();

void colouringAndCheckConflict(int i, int c) {
    bipartiteGraph[i] = c;
    int j;
    for (j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
        if (adjacencyMatrix[i][j]) {
            if (bipartiteGraph[j] == c) //conflict : not a bipartite graph
            {
                noSolution = 1;
                return;
            }
            if (!bipartiteGraph[j]) {
                colouringAndCheckConflict(j, 3 - c); // color the opposite color 1<->2
            }
        }
    }
}

void checkAdjacencyAndDye() {
    /* 231 for sortable
     * i<j<k, S[k]<S[i]<S[J]
     * 312 for generatable
     * k<i<j, S[i]<S[J]<S[k]
     * DONE: Modify the algorithm to make it right for generation instead of sortable
    */
    int i, j;
    precalculatedMax[0] = NEINF;
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        precalculatedMax[i] = targetPermutation[i];
        if (precalculatedMax[i - 1] > precalculatedMax[i])
            precalculatedMax[i] = precalculatedMax[i - 1];
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= N - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= N; j++) {
            if (targetPermutation[i] < targetPermutation[j] && precalculatedMax[i - 1] > targetPermutation[j]) {
                adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = adjacencyMatrix[j][i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (!bipartiteGraph[i] && !noSolution) {
            colouringAndCheckConflict(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

void reset() {
    memset(adjacencyMatrix, 0, sizeof(adjacencyMatrix));
    memset(bipartiteGraph, 0, sizeof(bipartiteGraph));
    memset(targetPermutation, 0, sizeof(targetPermutation));
    memset(precalculatedMax, 0, sizeof(precalculatedMax));
    N = 0;
    noSolution = 0;
}

int main() {

    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    int k;
    for (k = 1; k <= t; k++) {


        int i;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &targetPermutation[i]);

        }
        checkAdjacencyAndDye();
        if (!noSolution) {
            printf("Yes\n");
        } else {
            printf("No\n");
        }
        reset();
    }

    return 0;
}
```